# Print scientific and standard notation in same vector in R

Tags: r

I want R to print a vector with a mix of standard and scientific notation.

Why? It's easier to read.

Specifically, I have a vector of values of wildly divergent values between 0 and 1; some ranging in orders of magnitude from 10^-1 to 10^-16, and I'd like those of order 10^-1 or -2 to print in standard, and those much larger to print in scientific.

Currently I can only force R to do 1 or the other.

E.g.

```
> rrr <- c(0.12, 0.01333, 0.0000000000000003856)
> rrr
[1] 1.200e-01 1.333e-02 3.856e-16
```

or

```
> options(scipen = 12)
> rrr
[1] 0.1199999999999999956 0.0133299999999999998 0.0000000000000003856
```

So `scipen` appears to apply to a whole vector, rather than to each element. Likewise, altering e.g. `options(digits = 2)` just rounds the smallest number, to `0.00000000000000039`

What I would like to see is

```
> rrr
[1] 0.12 0.013333 3.856e-16
```

Thoughts?

Thanks, you're all legends for reading this far!

[Also, I don't understand the un-rounding behaviour when `scipen = 12`, but that's another issue...]

Comment: If it is ok to have the values as a string, would the following work for you: set `options(scipen = 5)` to control which numbers will be in scientific notation, and then `sapply(rrr, function(x) as.character(x))`

Comment: Thanks @steveb, not ideal, but workable

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to do ?  My suggestions is just for display, if you want R to automatically selectively use (or not use) scientific notation, but keep them as numeric values, I don't think R can currently do that.

Comment: *"scipen appears to apply to a whole vector"*: more apt, it applies to a `class`, and a vector only contains one class for all of it (same for `array`s, btw). The only time you get multiple classes together is in a `list` or `list`-based object. As for your "unrounding", it's likely related to [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f).)

Comment: Yep what I wanted was "R to automatically selectively use (or not use) scientific notation, but keep them as numeric value", but ultimately it's  just so it's easier for me to read off and transfer to tables externally for display, so your solution works well for that, though seems to still want to use 15 sig figs...

Comment: Thanks also @r2evans; mind blown!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most certainly a hack, and it's incomplete to boot: the "awesome" way would be for this function to behave as most S3-based functions and actually be called when a numeric object is "printed".

Also, it is far from complete. In this case, it assumes a vector and does not take into account things like console-width, equal spacing, etc.

But it's a start (of an example for "play"), showing how one "might" approach dealing with an OCD such as this :-)

```
options(scipen2 = 3)
print.numeric <- function(x, ...) {
  scipen2 <- getOption("scipen2", default = 3)
  cat(c(ifelse(abs(log(x, 10L)) >= scipen2,
               format(x, digits = 5, scientific = TRUE),
               format(x, digits = 1, scientific = FALSE)),
        "\n"))
}

print(c(101, NA, pi / 100, pi / 10000, 1/100, pi * 10000))
#   101.0000 NA     0.0314 3.1416e-04     0.0100 3.1416e+04
```

I don't recommend this for production use. I don't even recommend it for development use, unless you are happy being prone to breakage, bad formatting, etc. Perhaps it'll spark some thoughts and/or conversation. (But it really isn't fit for anything other than discussions of curiosity.)

Answer (score 1):

Taking [steveb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4411559/steveb) comment one step further:

```
rrr <- c(0.12, 0.01333, 0.0000000000000003856)
#the foom calculates the order of magnitude of the number. Division by 1000 set the
# number of digits to preserve - 3 more than the order of magnitude
foom <- function(x) {
  -round(log10(abs(x/1000)),0)
}
#round by foom and print as charecter
sapply(round(rrr,foom(rrr)), function(x) as.character(x))

#[1] "0.12"     "0.01333"  "3.86e-16"
```